# Adding class to jQuery object that has been passed to a function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery function that adds a class (`.dataerror`) to various html elements if they are empty. First, I'm doing this:

```
$('.editable').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).html()) {
        showerror($(this));
    }
});
```

And a super-simplified version of the function looks like this:

```
function showerror(element) {
    $(element).addClass('dataerror');
}
```

However, this DOES NOT add the class to the elements if they are empty.

If I change the function to:

```
function showerror(element){
    $(element).hide();
}
```

...then the elements ARE hidden as expected if they are empty.

Can anyone tell my why `.addClass()` DO NOT work on the element in this context, while other methods such as `.hide()` DO work?

Thx.

Comment: what element types are you adding the ".editable" class to?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(element).addClass('dataerror');
```

can u try

```
element.addClass('dataerror');
```

Comment: Yep, you have that working as expected there, but I can't get it to work here. Some jQuery methods like `.hide()` work but I can't get `.addClass()` to work. Weird.

I need to look into the rest of my code. :o)

Comment: what version of jquery u use?
checking in which browser ?

Comment: 1.10.2 and latest Chrome & Safari on Mavericks.

Comment: I'm also running a couple of jQuery plugins which may be screwing things up here.

Comment: after $(element).addClass('dataerror'); can u add 
alert(element.attr('class')); and check

Comment: OK, that's really weird. The alert pops up and shows the correct class, and the element actually displays with that class.

But when I close the alert, the element loses the class again.

Comment: does the page refresh? try return false instead of alert

Comment: It's OK - I think I've fixed it. I was removing the class again a few lines down. Been looking at this waaay too long! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Use `showerror(this);` instead of `showerror($(this))` because you are wrapping the DOM element into a jquery object twice.

Comment: Yep, see the fiddle from @abhiklpm below. I must have something else going on although I'm not getting any js errors or conflicts. Thx.